How can i make sure that a Typescript function still executes while the other function is blocked?
I have a function which handles incoming messages. I am adding logic which sorts messages based on priority (and stores the sorted order in a Redis Sorted Set). This is done by the sortMessage() & extractMessage() functions which use Lua scripts to do Redis operations.

    public async handleMessage(message: Message) {
        const messageReceivedTime = Date.now();

        await this.redisMessageSorter.sortMessage(message, messageReceivedTime);


        const extractedMessage = await this.redisMessageSorter.extractMessage(message.brandId); //is rate limited

//other logic
        
    }

The extractMessage() function is rate limited in order to provide enough time to let the incoming messages get sorted by sortMessage()-
public async extractMessage(brandId: string | undefined): Promise<Message | null> {
        const client = await this.redisPool.acquire();
        await this.rateLimiter.removeTokens(1);

        try {
            const heapKey = `message_heap`;
            const brandLastTsKey = `brand_last_ts:${brandId}`;

            const extractedMessage = await client.eval(this.extractScript, {
                keys: [heapKey, brandLastTsKey],
                arguments: [],
            });

            if (extractedMessage) {
                const extractedMessageString = String(extractedMessage);
                return JSON.parse(extractedMessageString) as Message;
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        } finally {
            this.redisPool.release(client);
        }
    }

I am facing problems when testing this by sending some requests. When the extractMessage() function is being rate-limited, execution of sortMessage() is also being blocked (therefore preventing message sorting).
I've tried to use a .then() block around the extractMessage() function to bypass this problem, but that just offset the problem by only letting the next batch of messages into the Redis heap (as opposed to all the sent messages).
How can I make sortMessage() still execute while extractMessage() is being blocked?
